# latex \cite shows all the field in the text

Tags: biblatex

I am new to LaTeX, and at this moment I am writing my thesis paper using Turabian style. I am trying to cite using `\cite` but rather than showing "(Author last name, year)" or even "[number]" it's showing me whole reference fields. I just want "(last name, year)". Example:

```
have been successful in finding equation \cite{einstein}
```

But it outputs:

> have been successful in finding equation Albert Einstein, “Zur
>   Elektrodynamik bewegter K ̈orper,” Annalen der Physik 322, no. 10 (1905):891–921. doi:http:/dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004

In the bibliography section, it does show the reference

> Einstein, Albert.  “Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K ̈orper.”
>   Annalen der Physik
>   322, no. 10
>   (1905):  891–921.  doi:
>   http:/dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004
>   .

This is what I have inside by .bib file and main.tex file

```
@article{einstein,
author = {Albert Einstein},
title = {Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper},
journal = {Annalen der Physik},
volume = {322},
number = {10},
pages = {891--921},
year = {1905},
DOI = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\addbibresource{backmatter/works-cited.bib}
\printbibliography
```

This could be an easy fix, but since I am new to LaTex I couldn't figure out the issue. Hence, I came here for help.

Comment: You want `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}`. And probably you also want to know about `\parencite` and `\textcite`.

Comment: By default `biblatex-chicago` is in so-called `note` mode and prints full citations. If you want shorter author-year citations load `\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}`. You may want to use `\autocite` instead of `\cite`. The `bibentry` package is not needed.

Comment: Thanks guys, both the answers worked.

Comment: @DavidPurton Merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `biblatex-chicago` uses note style references. You need to pass it the `authordate` option.

Also, `\cite` just prints the citation, but you want it in parentheses. To do this you should either use `\autocite`, which puts citations in the format that makes most sense for the current `biblatex` style, or `\parencite` which forces the citation to appear in parentheses.

You may also find `\textcite` helpful which is designed for running text and just places the year in parentheses.

Also as an aside, `biblatex` prefers the `date` field over the `year` field. `date` allows for much more flexibility in specifying dates.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{einstein,
  author = {Albert Einstein},
  title = {Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik},
  volume = {322},
  number = {10},
  pages = {891-921},
  date = {1905},
  doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\verb|\cite{einstein}|: \cite{einstein}

\verb|\autocite{einstein}|: \autocite{einstein}

\verb|\parencite{einstein}|: \parencite{einstein}

\verb|\textcite{einstein}|: \textcite{einstein}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: We could also write `Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter Körper` and exploit that `biblatex` (with Biber) can deal with Unicode. One would probably want to add `langid = {german},` to the entry to preserve capitalisation in styles with sentence case.